# Powershell, file.exe --help output not redirectable

Tags: windows, powershell, redirection

I'm attempting to redirect the output of the help message from a binary to an output.txt file, but the help message isn't being redirected as expected. I've tried several different solutions, but none have worked. Here are the commands I've tried (I've tried transcript to and it doesn't work):

```
PS D:\user\drivers> wmic process call create ".\drivers.exe -h" > output.txt

PS D:\user\drivers> cat .\output.txt
Exécution (Win32_Process)->Create()

Méthode exécutée.

Paramètres de sortie :
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 9;
};
PS D:\user\drivers> $output = Invoke-Expression ".\drivers.exe -h"
PS D:\user\drivers>
PS D:\user\drivers> $output|  Out-File -FilePath ".\output.txt"
PS D:\user\drivers> cat .\output.txt
PS D:\user\drivers> .\drivers.exe -h | Out-File -FilePath ".\output.txt"

Usage: /s /e /f <target-path>
  /s - Un-package the package in silent mode (not showing user interaction UI)
  /f - Runtime switch that overrides the default target path specified in build time
  /e - Prevent execution of default executable file specified in build time.
       Only extracting the content files to target folder(Use this with /s /f)
PS D:\user\drivers> cat .\output.txt
```

Comment: This seems like an x-y problem. What exactly is it what you want to achieve, and why do you need the help section of that command? Also, what exactly from the help do you need? I think the last section to capture the help to $output is enough, and you can just modify $output itself without even sending it to output.txt and only once you're done, and you still need output.txt, dump it to that then.

Comment: Also, I think the `drivers.exe -h` option is not actually what displays the help, but rather `drivers.exe` without any parameter.

Answer (score 2):

That output looks like it might be getting sent as an error instead of standard output. Try redirecting `stderr` (`2>`) to a file instead, like below

```
.\drivers.exe -h 2> output.txt
```

Or to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
.\drivers.exe -h 2>&1 > output.txt
```

---

See more info about handling output in: [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: It's also not impossible that the program is bypassing the standard streams entirely, in which case the output can't be captured.